# im trying to remove certain text from .txt files

Tags: text, lines

I hav pdf files that have security marks on the top right and left of the pagei convert them to .pdb files to read them on my phone and it puts the writing in the security marks into the .pdb file so that every few pages has:

```
PDF Transform

PDF Transform

Y

Y

Y

er

Y

er

B

2

B

2

B

.0

B

.0

A

A

Click here to buy

Click here to buy

w

w

w

w

w .

w

A B B YY.com

.A B BYY.com
```

I've tried converting them to multiple types of files using `calibre` but it shows up in all of them.

If I convert them to `.txt` files can anyone make a batch file that will erase these lines of text in multiple files?

Comment: What platform, language and technology do you intend to use/have available?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which OS you are on but this will work on *nix, osx with SED installed, not sure if you can use SED in windows:

```
for filename in *.txt; do sed ${filename} -e '1,20d' -e '/^PDF Transform/,/^A B B YY\.com/d' > newfiles/${filename}; done
```

First -e command removes lines 1-20 if you know it's something static and in the same position inside of the file. Second -e command will remove everything between PDF Transform and YY.com including these lines. You can use many or one -e commands to get what you want. It assumes that newfiles folder does exist. I didn't test this so regex might be off.

Comment: stupid question first what is SED???.. second question is will it get rid of all instances of this in the book?? as it doesnt just happen at the beginning of the book it happens throught the book on every page so theres more than one instance of it.

Comment: sorry im kinda new to this the last programing i did was on a "trash 80 coco3" when i edited a txt moon colony game

Comment: sed is a command line text editing utility, http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html, yes the second command will remove it throughout the file. In basic terms, it's an advanced find/replace utility.

Comment: k tried fooling around with it and it says it cant find the directory

Comment: i was doing this in the cmd window and it says it cant find the directory so to simplify it for myself i converted a book to .txt and put it into a c:\sed dir and renamed it to test.txt. so using this dir and file where would i put this into the cmd line that i was given so that it works?? or was that line i was given to be put into a batch file so i only have to type the cmd i choose and the file name.. as i said it has been about 30 years since i've done stuff like this.

Comment: sed '/^PDF Transform/,/^\.A B BYY\.com/d' c:\sed\test.txt > c:\sed\new.txt
try it like this. I don't have windows machine so I can't really test it. You might have to specify full path to sed or be inside of the folder where sed executable is.

Comment: of i figured out how to do it without sed and i dont have to convert them from pdf i can do it using nitro pro and i can just cover it up and set it to copy to all pages then save the file again

Comment: thnx for all your help though guys!! you guys rock!